# error while free memory if we use memcpy

Tags: c++, c

While using `memcpy` and free memory, `free` is giving a heap corruption. I don't understand why.

```
char *buff = malloc(20);
memset(buff,NULL,20);
strcpy(buff,"xvxvxvxxvx");
char*time =  malloc(20));
memset(time,NULL,20);//memcpy use
memcpy(time,buff,20);
free(time);//crashing here
return 0;
```

Comment: memset(buff, `0`, 12); The second parameter of `memset` is an `int` not a pointer as `NULL` would suggest.

Comment: And in C it is a bad habit to typecast the return value of `malloc`. In C++ it is bad style to even use `malloc`. So there is no excuse to typecast.

Comment: malloc return void pointer. if i will not do typecast, it will give error. its all depend compiler

Comment: In C it doesn't. If you get a compiler error, you're using C++ (a different language) and shouldn't use `malloc`, `free`in the first place (`new`, `delete` is the C++ way). If you get a warning in C, it means you haven't included the right headers (stdlib.h or memory.h), which means you have a bug in your program that the typecast hid.

Comment: RANT: C and C++ are two very different languages. Learn C or learn C++, but never think that C is only a subset of C++, it is not. IMO it was the most retarded idea of Stroustrup to build a language on this idea. The confusion it generated has probably cost dearly to humanity. RANT OFF

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof(20)` is the size of an `int`. You probably intended `malloc(20)` for 20 chars.

Comment: To clarify: Instead of doing sizeof(20), do 20*sizeof(char) for example

Comment: ´sizeof (char)´ is by definition always 1. So no need to multiply by 1. `malloc(20)`will do.

Comment: @tristopia, Personally, if I saw a `sizeof(char)` rather than a magic number (1), it would be so much more readable.

Comment: Ok, but if I fixed that also it will crash due to memcpy and free..If i use strcpy and free. it will work fine. but my requirement is to use memcpy.

Comment: @user2268978 the code in your question should not crash. Are you compiling different code than you posted?

Answer (score 0):

second argument of memset expects int but is is receiving NULL.

void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);

The memset() function fills the first n bytes of the memory area pointed to by s with the constant byte c.

So you can use memset as 
memset(buff,0,20);
now the program will not crash.